# Python 3.9 - List index out of range error when interating through .csv, pseudosolved through adding a print statement. Possible Bug?

Tags: python, csv

Using the standard csv lib for python 3.9.3
For context I'm writing a quick script for importing a .csv file into an sqlite3 database.
I'm running in a virtualenv, running from root python has the same effect.

```
# Generate sqlite3 database from .csv
import sqlite3
import csv

data = []
with open('data.csv', newline='') as csvfile: # read .csv file
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',') # read the data into nested lists
    iterreader = iter(reader)
    next(iterreader) # skip one line (heading line in .csv)
    for row in iterreader: # iterate through nested array, each row is a list obj
        # everything is str() must convert certain values in the list as below.
        row[0] = int(row[0]) 
        row[6] = int(row[6])
        row[7] = float(row[7])
        row[8] = float(row[8])
        row[10] = int(row[10])
        data.append(row) # append the updated row to the initialized list
print(data)
```

Outputs:

```
    $ python databasegen.py
    $ row[0] = int(row[0]) Index Error: list index out of range
```

What's interesting is that by adding a print statement of the row, anywhere in the loop.
It works.

```
# Generate sqlite3 database from .csv
import sqlite3
import csv

data = []
with open('data.csv', newline='') as csvfile: # read .csv file
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',') # read the data into nested lists
    iterreader = iter(reader)
    next(iterreader) # skip one line (heading line in .csv)
    for row in iterreader: # iterate through nested array, each row is a list obj
        # everything is str() must convert certain values in the list as below.
        print(row) # just prints the row prior to conversion
        row[0] = int(row[0]) 
        row[6] = int(row[6])
        row[7] = float(row[7])
        row[8] = float(row[8])
        row[10] = int(row[10])
        data.append(row) # append the updated row to the initialized list
print(data)
```

Outputs:

```
    $ python databasegen.py
    $ ['1', '2', '3', '4' ...]... and so forth
```

Adding a print statement after changing the types still works.

```
# Generate sqlite3 database from .csv
import sqlite3
import csv

data = []
with open('data.csv', newline='') as csvfile: # read .csv file
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',') # read the data into nested lists
    iterreader = iter(reader)
    next(iterreader) # skip one line (heading line in .csv)
    for row in iterreader: # iterate through nested array, each row is a list obj
        # everything is str() must convert certain values in the list as below.
        row[0] = int(row[0]) 
        row[6] = int(row[6])
        row[7] = float(row[7])
        row[8] = float(row[8])
        row[10] = int(row[10])
        print(row) # prints the row post conversion
        data.append(row) # append the updated row to the initialized list
print(data)
```

Outputs:

```
    $ python databasegen.py
    $ [1, '2', '3', '4' ...]... and so forth
```

I'm unsure if this is an error in my code, however I'm leaning towards a bug in python.
I can use pandas if need be, however I find it interesting and unexpected behavior.
If this format is incorrect, apologies, I haven't used stackoverflow before nor needed to.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: It would be surprising if this was a bug in Python or even the csv module. Since you didn't provide data that reproduces the error, there's not much anyone can do other than guess.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. I made a test CSV file and tried this in a Python 3.9.3 Docker container and your code worked. Could you create a [mre] with the CSV data you're using? Please verify that the MRE reproduces the problem exactly as is without any modification or other environmental tweaks.

Comment: as an aside, `iterreader = iter(reader)` is pointless, `reader` is already an iterator, `iter(reader)` simply returns `reader`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .csv data had a `\n` newline at the end. Removing the newline solved the issue.
This would be due to the `open()` method. I believe it was a result of using `newline=''`, this means when the `csv.reader()` method is called it packages all of the rows into lists. Including the newline. So there is an empty list at the very end of the array. This means that when it calls for the first object with `list()[0]`, it returns an error because of the empty list.

Comment: So printing had nothing to do with it?

Comment: Nobody is going to sit and wait for the script to iterate through hundreds of thousands of points waiting for them to print. If I left it, the same error would have risen at the very end. So yes, printing only gave the illusion of it working.